# Is there any way to middle the text on the image (Python/PIL)?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Here is my code:

```py
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import names

name = names.get_first_name(gender="male")

template = Image.open("imgs/banner.png")
font_type = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(template)
draw.text(xy=(50, 50), text=f"Hello, {name}", fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font_type)
template.save(f"banner-{name}.png")
```

I would like to middle the text.

Thats my "template" ([original url](https://discordjs.guide/assets/img/8CQvVRV.cced9193.png)):

[image]

Comment: Please put a look at [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66953516/941531) for your task!

Answer (score 0):

Here I improved your code to do what you want:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66953315#main.py)

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import names

name = names.get_first_name(gender="male")

template = Image.open("banner.png")
font_type = ImageFont.truetype("arial.ttf", 40)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(template)
text = f"Hello, {name}"
text_size = font_type.getsize(text)
draw.text(xy=(
    (template.size[0] - text_size[0]) // 2, (template.size[1] - text_size[1]) // 2),
    text=text, fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font_type)
template.save(f"banner-{name}.png")
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to the one suggested by Arty is to use the `anchor` parameter implemented in Pillow 8. See [the Pillow documentation on text anchors](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/text-anchors.html) for more information. In short, the value `'mm'` can be used to both horizontally and vertically align the text around the coordinates filled in to the `xy` argument.

```
draw.text(xy=(template.width / 2, template.height / 2),
          text=f"Hello, {name}", fill=(255, 255, 255), font=font_type,
          anchor='mm')
```

[image: banner with centered text]